# Serverless: TypeError: Cannot destructure property `timeout` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Since the last version update of my packages, my Serverless offline gives me the error each time an API is called.

My Provider is AWS and the code get deployed to lambda.

[image: Error]

**The serverless.yml file**

```
service:
  name: race-suite-backend

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-offline-sqs

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

package:
  exclude:
    - src/layers/**
```

Though the bug doesn't seem to be deadly. But its better late than never.

Comment: Relevant https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/649